# Android button listener

Tags: android, button, listener

I am trying to implement an button listener which sets a value true when the button is hold down
and set it false when it is realised

But how can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you:

```
public class ButtonDownListener implements OnTouchListener{

    boolean pressed = false;

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        if(event == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            pressed = true;
        }
        else if(event == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            pressed = false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

registered to button:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new ButtonDownListener());
```

Comment: JRaymond and I have nearly the same suggestions... what is not working for you?

Comment: By now I found a solution I had to change "MotionEvent.Action_UP" to "MotionEvent.1"

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
public void foo() {
  Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mButton)

  mButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          mBoolean = true;
          return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          mBoolean = false;
          return true;
        default:
          return false;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Granted there are some issues with multithreaded operations with the above code (for instance, the bool in question should probably be atomic, etc.), but it's the typical implementation of a single touch listener.  A multi touch listener adds a few more cases to the switch, but the idea is still the same.

Comment: How do you mean? won't compile? doesn't change the boolean? The code that's supposed to be impacted by this boolean isn't running?